# How to execute a CustomSqlChange manually

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, liquibase, changeset, liquibase-sql

I'm writing a [CustomSqlChange](https://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/change/custom/CustomSqlChange.html) for the first time and want to test the outcome by running it on my current database. Of course I could start up the application and execute all change sets via liquibase (including the one that executes my `CustomSqlChange`), but that takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to manually execute the java class implementing `CustomSqlChange` from my IDE (IntelliJ) as if it would be from liquibase? Could one maybe even debug that execution?

Comment: Yes, use a unit tests. Liquibase has plenty that should help you to get going.

Comment: what about generating output sql with `updateSQL`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate changelog file, where only your's custom change will be included. Point Liquibase to use it instead of base one. This will give you ability to debug it as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog .....>
    <changeSet id="custom-change" author="author" runOnChange="true" >
        <customChange param="..." /> 
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```